# How do you remove slug altogether from custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types

For a custom post type page I'd like to completely remove the slug so that the URL structure mirrors http://my-domain.com/CPT-title/ or http://my-domain.com/CPT-category/CPT-title .  If I set the rewrite parameter to

```
'rewrite' => array('slug' => '', 'with_front' => false)
```

Wordpress freaks out and I get 404 on all pages except for the CPT page.  If I don't define slug at all, then it defaults to the CPT name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set 'slug' to false and not a blank string.

Comment: I had tried the same code and had a problem, you're saying to set `'slug'` to false so is this right or wrong `'rewrite' => array('slug'=>false,'with_front'=>false),` this doesn't work for me the slug's still being generated. What should the code be? Thanks

Comment: Setting the slug to false (and refreshing permalinks) seems to create a redirect for me to the full URL WITH the CPT-name/page-name